# Restrict Android Device Wifi Connection‏

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

**How to force android to connect specifically defined wireless network**

Is it possible?

User should able to connect defined work wi-fi or wifis,

but should not access any other networks like home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly for what you want to do that?For your application or the device?

If it's your application you can do restrictions about connection type and network etc.

But if you are talking about the device you cant achieve something like that unless you have the control of the whole system which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you Serdar for answer, Its not an application level.
I can have control whole system. I need to create an modulated android os, but is it possible?

Comment: @Utku Yeah it's possible though you have to create your own custom rom and create your own Android Build for more info and lead check this. http://marakana.com/forums/android/general/275.html

Comment: Thank you. I will look it when i have time

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create an app or service that would pick up the:

```
NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION  Intent
```

And then in turn use the

```
WifiManager.getConnectionInfo()
```

to check whether this is a legitimate network, if not then just disconnect and notify the user.

Comment: can  i run this program at root level, so user can't close it